# Laravel Storage symlink

Tags: php, laravel, symlink

I'm trying to access files that are stored in storage/app/.../.../file.png.

I have created a symlink, linking my storage folder to  public/storage.

When I try to access the appropriate file, my server throws a 404, saying file not found. Clearly I'm not accessing it the right way but I dont know what to change.

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/app/puppy/18/ax2Fk08nyWrV6TwTOnsXNCkNGuIdFebB7TTfPYGb.png')}}" alt="">
```

[image]

Comment: Did you do `php artisan storage:link`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

when you create symlink in `laravel` then it create symlink of `storage/app/public` folder to `public/storage` folder. That means if you want to access any files publicly then place all your files inside `storage/app/public` folder and access it like this

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/puppy/18/test.png')}}" alt="">
```

Here it means the file `test.png` should be physically at `storage/app/public/puppy/18` folder.

Execute `php artisan storage:link` for creating symlink in laravel

Hope it clear you

Comment: You're amazing. You seem to be the one answering all of my questions the clearest.

Comment: ah, so glad to help you. happy coding

Comment: I have a laravel 6 app. Everything seems to be in place. But css and js are not loading. When I do ctrl + u I get this https://i.postimg.cc/Fs58WDJQ/Untitled.jpg and when I Inspect and go to network tab, I see 404 status. I do not know why. This is the github repo I am trying to use https://github.com/cmate5614530/inventory-management

Answer (score 3):

For shared hostings try below solutions

Code:

1) Remove storage folder in public_html/public/storage

2) Create a php file for example symlink.php in public_html folder

3) Add codes to symlink.php file

```
$targetFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage/app/public';
$linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/public/storage';
symlink($targetFolder,$linkFolder);
echo 'Symlink process successfully completed';
```

4) Go to web site example.com/symlink.php

That is all...

Video url from youtube => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svyN8-PjGHc

Comment: I can't reach the file, it gives 404 LOL

Comment: Probably something is wrong or your hosting provider don't support symlink

Comment: Nothing wrong with my hosting, it's normal that you can't reach files in root directory because we set the root directory for the domain to  domain.com/public. My hosting supports symlink and I  solved it through SSH

Comment: The idea worked for me! It did complain about failing to create the symlink, because `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` returned the path including the public folder. I ended up echoing the path and manually entering and altering the variables in the `symlink` function, which ran successfully!

Comment: @Tum Would you like to share what you did?

Comment: @Umair I first did something like `echo getcwd();` to know the path of uploaded files. I then manually entered the paths in the symlink-function, something like `symlink('/path/of/existing/folder', '/path/of/preferred/folder);`. It's a while back so I'm not sure about the exact things I entered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
<img src="{{asset('puppy/18/ax2Fk08nyWrV6TwTOnsXNCkNGuIdFebB7TTfPYGb.png')}}" alt="">
```