# 404 NOT FOUND. on clicking download cv button

Tags: laravel, html-table, download, assets

am getting 404 NOT FOUND on clicking cv
am using this

```
`<td class="border px-4 py-2"><a href="{{ asset('storage/cv_files/' . $student->cv_file) }}">{{ $student->cv_file }}</a>
</td>`
```

am getting 404 not found on this url

**http://localhost/storage/cv_files/cv_files/IrF7GnM9QXLehTjOwV4a9K5HiaQLwfUKQEU7LNgR.pdf**
but the file is in the correct folder that is Storage/app/cv_files

I have tried with different url routes still am getting this
i run the command already
**php artisan storage:link** and its successfully running

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `/storage/cv_files/` or `Storage/app/cv_files` instead of `storage/cv_files/`

Comment: http://localhost/storage/app/cv_filescv_files/ByuLKs5ASlUEz5f5iIew9W2oDRD6KiT1JqS3uJ4u.pdf
the path is correct but still getting 404 not found 
<a href="{{ asset('/storage/app/cv_files' . $student->cv_file) }}">{{ $student->cv_file }}</a>
now am using this

Answer (score 0):

the `{{asset()}}` helper points to the `public/` dir, you may need to add a symlink from your storage folder and public folder.

Check out this post [Laravel storage symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51676242/7440243)

Comment: @Vishal Kumar did this work for you